# Multiple CSS linear-gradients for background

Tags: css

I am trying to make the entire background of a page look like the image below with CSS, and I'm having difficulty using multiple linear-gradients together. The background has to have thin diagonal stripes with a top-to-bottom color fade that is lighter in the middle and fades to a darker color at the top and bottom.

I have tried a bunch of things and what I have here looks the best so far, but it's not quite right. Here is a [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/su3wf37h/3/) showing what I have.

I am okay with the stripes, but the top-to-bottom gradient is definitely off, as the gradient only shows on the transparent stripes. I think what is needed here, is two gradients that overlap somehow to get the effect below, but perhaps there is a better way.

Here is the code from the fiddle in case the link breaks in the future:

```
/* Stripes */
body {
    background: linear-gradient(
            -45deg,
            #5BABCF 25%,
            transparent 25%,
            transparent 50%,
            #5BABCF 50%,
            #5BABCF 75%,
            transparent 75%,
            transparent
    );
    background-size: 6px 6px;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Color Fade */
html {
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
            to bottom,
            #051219,
            #91B7CA 25%,
            transparent 50%,
            #91B7CA 75%,
            #051219 100%
    );
}
```

Any idea how to go about doing this?

[image: desired background pattern]

Comment: The stripes in the diagonal gradient should have a rgba color

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489892/two-linear-gradients-layers-on-div

Comment: Thank you vals, this is what I need. If you make it an answer, I will mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

Added opacity to the diagonal stripes in body

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient(
            -45deg,
            #5BABCF 25%,
            transparent 25%,
            transparent 50%,
            #5BABCF 50%,
            #5BABCF 75%,
            transparent 75%,
            transparent
    );
    background-size: 6px 6px;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 0.2;
}

/* Color Fade */
html {
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
            to bottom,
            #051219,
            #91B7CA 25%,
            transparent 50%,
            #91B7CA 75%,
            #051219 100%
    );
}
```

Comment: This works, although it looks like adding opacity to the body makes everything contained within the body have that same opacity. I think the comment from vals above using rgba colors is a better solution for my situation, because it only applies to the background property. I gave you an upvote anyways, because this is still a good answer, thank you.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that it fades everything in the body. And @vals answer is the best one. Thanks